# Are multiple flags on the same answer possible/allowed?

Tags: support, bug

I recently discovered that I had raised two flags on the same question.
I didn't know it could even be possible, as all other communities I know from the SE network don't allow more than one. And you have a written warning when trying to raise another flag on the same question/answer.

In the following case, I raised the "*spam*" flag, but not the "*rude*" one (and the answer isn't, anyway). A high-priority flag is enough to catch a user with privileges or a mod's attention.

Is this a feature or a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe multiple flags on the same answer are possible. I believe this is just a quirk of the UI, graying out all of the high priority flag options once you've used one of them.

Looking at the flag history of the answer on which your most recent spam flag was cast, that does appear to be the only flag from you.  There were four flags on the answer from four different users, and they were all spam flags.